# Spring Security 3.2, CSRF and multipart requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This question is in relation to the question at this url
[Spring Security 3.2 CSRF support for multipart requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397939/spring-security-3-2-csrf-support-for-multipart-requests/25183731?noredirect=1#comment39214621_25183731)

I tried this exact same setup as well as the gist but I cannot get this to work unless I have the _csrf token in the url. I had it in the form body as a hidden field and had the filter specified before the security filter but with no joy and it failed every time with the debug log message of an invalid csrf token

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Cheers Damien

Comment: It could come either from your environment or from a slight difference in config. To help narrowing the problem, can you run the project from the gist with no errors ?

Comment: I just created a new sample project based on a sample from Mkyong.com and followed the gist. Unfortunately, it is still not functioning for me. I have created a gist of all the relevant files and that is located here https://gist.github.com/damogallagher/26935a84b607df3ec46b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would have been very hard to find without the gist but I finally got it !

In fact it has nothing to do with Spring security. The real problem was only in SpringFramework multipart configuration. But because of it, the request appeared to have no parameter at all (neither `_csrf`, nor `file`) and the first to detect it was `CsrfFilter`. I removed everything about security, and the error was `Requested parameter file absent` (or something like it ...)

As detailed in [Spring Framework manual](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/), multipart can be handled in 2 ways:

- using Apache commons fileupload
- using servlet 3.0 configuration

  1. You followed first solution of the related post and configured a `CommonsMultipartResolver` in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. The first problem is that the `MultipartFilter` is related to the global ServletContext and looks for its `MultipartResolver` in root application context not in servlet specific context.

  The second problem it that you forgot to add a dependancy on Apache commons fileupload in your `pom.xml`.

  So you must first add this dependancy in your `pom.xml`

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  Next you must remove the `filterMultipartResolver` bean from `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and declare it in root application context. As a quick and dirty fix, you can add it into `spring-security.xml` :

  ```
  <beans:bean id="filterMultipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
      <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
  </beans:bean>
  ```

  2. An alternative configuration would have been to use the multipart handling of servlet 3.0.
     No need to depend on apache commons fileupload, nor to add any bean to the configuration, because `MultipartFilter` uses a `StandardServletMultipartResolver` as a default.

  You simply need to add a `<multipart-config>` element in the declaration of the `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml`

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <multipart-config>
          <!--location>/tmp</location-->
          <max-file-size>1000000</max-file-size>
      </multipart-config>
  </servlet>
  ```

Comment: Wow - such a simple solution in the end. Many thanks for your help in sorting this

Comment: How do we extract the MultipartFile [] in controller?I am using this MultipartRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartRequest) request; 

but getting 

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartRequest